# Concatenate large files without their top lines - python or bash?

Tags: python, linux, bash, concatenation, large-files

I've got 10 .txt files of genotypic data - each from a different chromosome.  They all have the same number of columns on each line, and the columns are already all in the same order. Each file starts with an identical first line.

What I'd like to do is attach all 10 files into a single genotype file in the order chr1, chr2, chr3...chr10.  However, I'd like to keep the header line ONLY from chr1, so it will remain a header, and remove all of the headers from subsequent chromosomes before attaching them all together.

For example, if I have:

file1:

```
chr, position, geno1, geno2
1, 100, A, C
1, 200, G, T
```

file2:

```
chr, position, geno1, geno2
2, 50, T, A
2, 150, C, G
```

I'd like to end with file_combined:

```
chr, position, geno1, geno2
1, 100, A, C
1, 200, G, T
2, 50, T, A
2, 150, C, G
```

What is the best/fastest way to do this, considering that the files are 400-600Mb apiece and the resulting file will be ~6Gb? I'm moderately comfortable writing Python and Linux shell scripts, but an explanation of why the code is quick and what it is doing would be a plus! Thanks!

Comment: Does it matter how fast it is?  i.e. is this a repeated process or something you'll do only once?

Comment: It won't be repeated regularly, though I do receive similarly sized data sets a couple times a year.  So no, it doesn't matter with regards to repetition, but also the sooner I can get working with it the better!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can do

```
cp chr1 output
for f in chr[2-9] chr10; do sed -n '2,$p' $f >> output; done
```

**update after comment**
indeed, it's even simpler with tail

```
cp chr1 output
tail -qn +2 chr[2-9] chr10 >> output
```

Comment: or, `tail -n +2 $f` :)

Answer (score 2):

The fastest way is not doing it.

For example, if you intend to feed this final file into a program, you can just use:

```
{
  head -n 1 file1
  for f in file{1..10}
  do
    tail -n +2 "$f"
  done
} | yourprogram
```

This will produce a stream exactly like you describe and feed it to your program, but will not waste time writing it to a file.

If you really do want a file, instead of `| yourprogram` you can use `> file`. This is more than good enough for your small amount of data.

When your data reaches the TB range, you can start thinking about preallocation and parallelizing writes across devices.